# Three column layout where content continues on the next column

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a layout with Bootstrap where I've got three even columns (I've done this). And I'd like a way to have paragraphs starting on the leftmost column and when they reach the end of this column (scrolling is disabled, this is meant to be a static frame) the content continues on the middle column from the top.

When it reaches the bottom of the middle column it should continue on the rightmost one where upon reaching the end it just hides the remaining content. These paragraphs could be collapsed and the content be adjusted across the columns accordingly.

I'm not sure if this is possible just with CSS and HTML of JS is also necessary (I'm not a Web frontend guy).

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you're asking using [CSS3 columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts). Instead of using bootstrap to create the three even columns, use CSS:

```css
.col-overflow-3 {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  height: 140px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-overflow-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the bootstrap container here isn't necessary, just added it in for context since you mentioned you're using it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It seems this continues the content on the next column before reaching the maximum vertical space available in the column. Is there a way to have the text on the left column only continue on the middle when it runs out of vertical space on the left column?

Comment: @SashaFonseca you're looking for the `column-fill` property; updated the example. Here's a decent reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-fill/

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks a lot @Nick

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using CSS3, then you can use column-count.

https://jsfiddle.net/L0pLkxp6/

```
    div {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    height: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Jason. I understand you were the first to answer but I found Nick's initial answer (before the edits) to be a bit more explicit so I marked him as the solution.